# Matlab access specific element from importfile

Tags: matlab

I have a data file “8545.txt” and I import the data using matlab and generate a matlab function (importfile.m) for that. So I have now the matlab generated file called ”importfile” and in the main program I write,

```
filename='8545.txt';
[t2,mass,time,chan,op,Com] = importfile(filename);
```

Now, if I want to access a specific value of “t2” for using in another place, how do I define an array (or something which works) which will enable me to access any specific value of “t2”. So, if t2 runs from 1 to 32, and I want to set some other variable in my code equal to a specific value of t2, i.e.  f[t2] == m   ….. something like that, how to do it?

For example, t2: 1 to 32, mass: 1 to 6, time: 0 to 64, chan: 1 to 4, op: 1 to 4, Com=complex number. So the data file looks like this:

```
1,1,1,1,1,3.273340e-08-1.351995e-09 i
1,1,1,1,2,6.339880e-09-1.015066e-09 i
1,1,1,1,3,-1.824081e-09-2.522303e-09 i
```

and so on. The last line is

```
32,6,64,4,4,-6.479969e-10-4.213433e-10 i
```

. So I would like to set some variable m equal to some specific value of t2

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's very unclear what you're asking. set some variable m equal to some specific value of t2? like `m = t2(i)` for some i? or are you asking how to find the value of `mass` (for example) that corresponds to a certain value of `t2`?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit for clarified question:**

This will let you access all of the complex numbers corresponding to t2==1.

```
m = Com(t2==1);
```

**Old answer:**

The problem is, that Matlab functions (like the one you just created) use a private workspace, inaccessible outside of the function. Scripts, however, store variables in the base workspace. Change the importfile.m from a function to a script (by deleting the function ... line at the beginning, and the end line at the end), and you'll be able to access your variables in other scripts.

Alternatively, you can export from the function workspace to the base workspace, although this isn't very commonly done:

```
assignin('base', 't2', t2);
```

Comment: They've set `t2` as an output variable, so it will be present in the base workspace after calling `[t2,mass,time,chan,op,Com] = importfile(filename);`.

Comment: That does appear to be a valid interpretation of the question. I'll agree then, that the question needs to be edited for clarity.

Comment: I meant "m" to be some other variable, not the mass. What i wanted is to define a variable, which will access only the complex numbers for which t2=1, then t2=2 and so on. As you see the last element has t2=32, so there are 6*64*4*4 rows for which t2=1, then another  6*64*4*4 rows for which t2=2 etc.